# Difference between "cat" command arguments "-b" and "-n"

Tags: cat

I am bit confuse about the command

```
cat filename.txt -b
```

and

```
cat filename.txt -n
```

They show the same output to the screen .Then what is the difference between them?

Comment: Manual pages are your friends, in terminal you can do 'man cat' to view explanation of each option

Answer (score 3):

In `cat`, `-b` shows the line numbers of non-empty lines, whereas `-n` shows the line numbers of all lines regardless of emptiness.

**Example:**

```
% cat -n file.txt 
     1  foo
     2  
     3  bar

% cat -b file.txt
     1  foo

     2  bar
```

Also note that `-b` overrides `-n` when used together:

```
% cat -bn file.txt
     1  foo

     2  bar
```

Comment: @ManishBharti no problem..consider accepting the solution so that this issue can be marked as solved..